# "Unlike" vs. "compared to"

Tags: word-usage

I've been reading a novel when I came across this sentence:

> Her being so helpless unlike her normal self made me a bit sad.

I want to ask about that "unlike" in the sentence. Is it correct to use it there, and if I replace it with "compared to", will the meaning of the sentence change?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster says that ***[unlike](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unlike)*** means  ***not characteristic of***, and it is correctly used in your sentence. ***[Compared to](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compared%20to)*** means *in relation to (something else) : measured or judged against (something else)*. I understand why you are thinking of ***compared to***, but these two expressions are not perfectly interchangeable.

Note that ***compared to her normal self*** is not idiomatic. [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unlike%20her%20normal%20self%2C%20compared%20to%20her%20normal%20self&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunlike%20her%20normal%20self%3B%2Cc0) finds no instance of it.

***Compared to*** is

> used when considering the size, quality, or amount of something in
> relation to something similar
>
> e.g.
>
> - Compared to our small flat, Bill’s house seemed like a
>   palace.

([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/compared-to-with-something))

Comment: "Having said that, both your....." - doesn't it need some clarity on 'who said'?

Comment: If you are talking about 'absolute construction', what you have used is not that. Anyway, you have now corrected/ edited it.  The previous one was wrong; else I wouldn't have raised it. If I were, I would have gladly accepted it and said, "I have modified it."  I know all people can't do that.

Comment: "In your earlier comment, "Having said that,..." was not followed by "I think". It was something like "Having said that,....both.......which was wrong; and that is what caught my attention. Now that you have edited it, it is correct.

Comment: I may also advise you to review your reply; you will definitely find scope for refining it, on other aspects...

Comment: @RamPilai: I have edited my answer after your comment.